# Haproxy: send custom http response when maxconn is hit

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

Is it possible to send a custom http response back from Haproxy if the load balancer hits maxconn?

My intention is to send a busy tone equivalent (but not 503) if the server is busy.

Answer (score 2):

The [errorfile](http://code.google.com/p/haproxy-docs/wiki/errorfile) keyword may be used in your configuration for this:

```
errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
```

Where 503.http is something like:

```
HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable^                                                                                      Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

<html><body><h1>503 Service Unavailable</h1>
Sorry, no server is available to handle this request.
</body></html>
```